# How to change colors of a highcharter matrix/heatmap?

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I'd like to change colors of a highcharter heatmap but can't seem to figure out the right way. In the following example, -1 is red and 1 is blue. I want to change the colors. E.g. -1 is blue and 1 is red.

```
mtcars2 <- mtcars[1:20, ]
x <- cor(mtcars2)
hchart(round(x,2),"heatmap")
```

When there are fewer than 12 variables, I can use `RColorBrewer` to change colors. For example:

```
hc_colorAxis(minColor = brewer.pal(12, "Set3")[1],
           maxColor = brewer.pal(12, "Set3")[12])
```

I have also tried `colorRampPalette()` to enable more colors, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I took example of The Impact of Vaccines plot in [highcharter showcase](http://highcharter%20showcase)

In this example the heatmap is not called from a matrix but from a data.frame with 3 columns, so I converted the correlation matrix to this format

```
library(tidyverse) # get the latest version for pivot_longer function   
mtcars3 <- cor(mtcars2) %>% 
              as.data.frame() %>% # convert to dataframe
              rownames_to_column(var="col1") %>% # add rownames as a new column
              pivot_longer(cols=names(mtcars),
                           names_to="col2",
                           values_to='cor') # convert to a 3 column dataframe
```

Then you can apply the colors with the code you provided, and added dataLabels parameter to show the values

```
hchart(mtcars3,"heatmap",hcaes(x=col1,y=col2,value=round(cor,2)),
               dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE)) %>%
   hc_colorAxis(minColor = brewer.pal(12, "Set3")[1],
           maxColor = brewer.pal(12, "Set3")[12])
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Thanks, @fmarm! It looks like it has something to do with the data structure. I wonder why it works on the matrix when there are fewer variables. Is it possible to get rid of or hide the col1 and col2 from the chart? In addition, `hchart(round(x,2),"heatmap")` will display the correlation figures on the chart. Can you show them on your chart too?

Comment: I have updated my answer, you need to add a  `dataLabels` paramter in the `hchart` call